# How can I iterate to the window control from a form

Tags: wpf, forms, window

How can I iterate to the window control from a form in the below hiearchy?
Windows.Forms--> WPF UserControl --> WPF Window(Using ShowDialog).
LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren does not catch the Window object.

Comment: Please give more details what you wanna reach and example of code would be also great.

Comment: I have a forms application. In that have a Windows.Forms. In that I added an element host. To that I added a WPF usercontrol. WPF Usercontrol has a button and on button click it Opens a Window control which is derived from WPF Window. WindowControl wc = new WindowControl();
            wc.Show();    Iam finding the child controls using IEnumerable children = LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(parent); But i dont get the window

Answer (score 0):

*A window that is opened by calling Show does not automatically have a relationship with the window that opened it; specifically, the opened window does not know which window opened it. This relationship can be established using the Owner property and managed using the OwnedWindows property.* FRom here - [Window.Show Method()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.show(v=vs.110).aspx)

But you can't set `Owner` for your WPFWindow because 'Owner' property can get only WPFWindow but you have as owner WinForms window. Maybe you can just save `WindowControl` as instance variable in you class so then you can get it any time you want.

Comment: Currently Iam declaring as    WindowControl wc = new WindowControl();
            wc.Show(); Can I get the every opened WPF windows from forms control?

Comment: `WindowControl` it is your own class which derived from `System.Windows.Window`?

Comment: Yes   public partial class WindowControl : Window

Comment: You can create a list where you can put reference to new window when it opens. And remove it from the list `OnClose` event.